# Selecting multiple rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Example table "comments"]

I need to select multiple comments (if there are any) based on the photo_id. As I understand it you can use the WHERE clause but I'm not exactly sure how to select multiple ones and store them in some kind of array?

e.g.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE photo_id='$photo1id'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); // but there's more than 1 row
```

If for example `$photo1id == 21`, how do I get all the comments (2 in this case)? Some kind of while loop?

At the end of the PHP file I have this:

```
echo json_encode(array('photo1id'=>$photo1id));
```

I need to store each row in that array somehow because I need to retrieve the data in another PHP file using $.getJSON. Or perhaps there is a better solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Loop` through it and generate an `array` -

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $comments[] = $row;
}
```

After that you can send the array as `json`.

```
echo json_encode($comments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there is more rows, you need to use a loop.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
//Run query
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE photo_id='$photo1id'");

//While there is a result, fetch it
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Do what you need to do with the comment
}
```

If you don't want to print the code straight away you can just create an array:

```
$x=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $comment[$x]=$row['comment'];
    $x++;
}
```